# exe obtained with pyinstaller works correctly only when launched from the venv. If double clicked it works (no errors) but results are not printed

Tags: python, pyinstaller

This sounds like a really strange problem.
I created a simple script, through tkinter it asks a series of questions and at the end creates a folder "Results" where it writes 5 text files.
The executable is created correctly through pyinstaller. If through prompt conda I navigate to the folder where the executable is and start it, everything works correctly (dialogs, folder creation, printing results), if I double click or run it from the cmd windows prompt the executable starts, the dialogs work, it creates the results folder but does not write the files!

Any idea about why? I really can't understand why the folder is created while files are not (so it is not a matter of write permission) and why the same exe works in one case and in one case it doesn't!

Here is the complete code. When I use pyinstaller I use the options -F, --exclude-packages PyQt5 and --hidden-import="sklearn.utils._cython_blas"

```
from numpy import shape
import pandas as pd

from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox, simpledialog
import tkinter as tk 
import os

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler,StandardScaler
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform



def scale_by_matrix(w):
    '''
    This function linearly scales wtx file 
    setting max value of matrix = 1 and min value = 0.
    '''
    M = w.max().max()
    m = w.min().min()
    
    w_scaled = (w-m)/(M-m)
    return w_scaled




#Choose nna file via interface
file_chose = tk.Tk()
file_chose.filename =  filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = os.getcwd(), title="Select NNA file",filetypes = (("nna files","*.nna"),("all files","*.*")))
nna = pd.read_csv(file_chose.filename, header=None, sep = '\t', )
file_nna=file_chose.filename

work_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(file_nna))
os.chdir(work_dir)
file_chose.filename =  filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = os.getcwd(), title="Select VAR file",filetypes = (("var files","*.var"),("all files","*.*")))
var = pd.read_csv(file_chose.filename, header=None, sep = '\t', )

tgt = messagebox.askyesno("target","Is there any target?")
if tgt:
    num_tgt = simpledialog.askinteger("target", "How many tagets?", parent=file_chose, minvalue=0, maxvalue=1000)
else:
    num_tgt = 0


file_chose.destroy()
dir_ = f'{work_dir}\\Results\\'

if not os.path.exists(dir_):
    os.makedirs(dir_)
os.chdir(dir_)


name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file_nna))[0]
name_no_dim = name.split('(')[0]

#remove NaN
nna = nna.dropna(axis = 0, how = 'all')
nna = nna.dropna(axis = 1, how = 'all')

nna_all = nna
if tgt:
    target = nna.iloc[:,-num_tgt:]
    nna = nna.iloc[:,:-num_tgt]

#num var and records
M,N = shape(nna)



#data scaling

app = tk.Tk()

minmax = messagebox.askyesno('scaling', 'Do you want a linear scaling?\n(If NO, a standard scaling will be computed)')
if minmax:
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    scaling ='MinMax'
else:
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    scaling ='StSc'
    
mode_eu = messagebox.askyesno('mode', 'Do you want EU?\n(If NO, CORR will be computed)')
if mode_eu:
    mode = 'EU'
else:
    mode = 'CORR'
app.destroy()    



nna = scaler.fit_transform(nna)

pca_name = f'{dir_}[PCA][{scaling}]{name}.nna'
pca_name_T = f'{dir_}[PCA][{scaling}][{mode}]{name_no_dim}({N}x{N}).wtx'
pca_name_T_tgt = f'{dir_}[PCA][{scaling}][{mode}]{name_no_dim}({N+num_tgt}x{N+num_tgt}).wtx'
pca_name_r = f'{dir_}[PCA][{scaling}]{name_no_dim}({N+num_tgt}x{M})_record.nna'
pca_name_r_wtx = f'{dir_}[PCA][{scaling}][{mode}]{name_no_dim}({M}x{M})_record.wtx'



pca = PCA(n_components = N)
principalComponents = pca.fit_transform(nna)
principalDf = pd.DataFrame(data = principalComponents)

if mode == 'EU':
    distances = pdist(principalDf.values, metric='euclidean')
    dist_matrix = squareform(distances)
elif mode== 'CORR':
    distances = pdist(principalDf.values, metric='correlation')
    dist_matrix = squareform(distances)
wtx = 1-dist_matrix   


with open(pca_name, 'w') as file_pca:
    if tgt:
        principalDf = pd.concat([principalDf, target], axis = 1)
    principalDf.to_csv(file_pca, header = False, index = False, sep = '\t', line_terminator = '\n', encoding = 'UTF-8')

with open(pca_name_r, 'w') as file_pca:
    #non aggiungo tgt perché già fatto prima
    principalDf = principalDf.T
    principalDf.to_csv(file_pca, header = False, index = False, sep = '\t', line_terminator = '\n')

with open(pca_name_r_wtx, 'w') as file_pca:
    wtx_ = pd.DataFrame(wtx)
    wtx_ = scale_by_matrix(wtx_)
    wtx_.to_csv(file_pca, header = True, index = False, sep = '\t', line_terminator = '\n')


pca_T = PCA(n_components = min(N,M))
principalComponents_T = pca_T.fit_transform(nna.T)
principalDf_T = pd.DataFrame(data = principalComponents_T.T)


if mode == 'EU':
    distances = pdist(principalDf_T.values, metric='euclidean')
    dist_matrix = squareform(distances)
elif mode == 'CORR':
    distances = pdist(principalDf_T.values, metric='correlation')
    dist_matrix = squareform(distances)
wtx = 1-dist_matrix   

 

with open(pca_name_T, 'w') as file_pca:
    wtx_ = pd.DataFrame(wtx)
    wtx_ = scale_by_matrix(wtx_)
    if num_tgt:
        wtx_.columns = var.values[:-num_tgt,0]
    else:
        wtx_.columns = var.values[:,0]
    wtx_.to_csv(file_pca, header = True, index = False, sep = '\t', line_terminator = '\n')
# print('file creato')        

pca_T = PCA(n_components = N+num_tgt)
principalComponents_T = pca_T.fit_transform(nna_all.T)
principalDf_T = pd.DataFrame(data = principalComponents_T.T)


if mode == 'EU':
    distances = pdist(principalDf_T.values, metric='euclidean')
    dist_matrix = squareform(distances)
elif mode == 'CORR':
    distances = pdist(principalDf_T.values, metric='correlation')
    dist_matrix = squareform(distances)
wtx = 1-dist_matrix    

with open(pca_name_T_tgt, 'w') as file_pca:
    wtx_ = pd.DataFrame(wtx)
    wtx_ = scale_by_matrix(wtx_)
    wtx_.columns = var.values[:,0]
    wtx_.to_csv(file_pca, header = True, index = False, sep = '\t', line_terminator = '\n')
```

Comment: The code is written in conda? What are all the imports done?

Comment: Yes, I'm using a virtual env in conda. I'm posting the complete code. I'm aware it is not a great script but the problem is really weird.